# Clarification on flagging "worked for me" answers as NAA

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

A few hours ago, I flagged a post as NAA; it is now deleted, but hopefully, some of you can see it:

[First Flutter App error: cannot resolve symbol "Properties"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938436/first-flutter-app-error-cannot-resolve-symbol-properties/69745278#69745278)

The complete text of the answer

> I have the same issue. Removing 'new' resolved my problem.

The flag was marked helpful, but the accompanying text from the moderator confused me; it said:

> This is an answer. A "Not an Answer" flag is inappropriate. It may be a duplicate answer. **It may be primarily a "worked for me" answer, but those need explanation, which should be in a custom flag**.

I've emphasized the part that confuses me.  I'd like to align my flagging with the goals of Stack Overflow. Looking through the NAA posts here, I found the [Meta.SO FAQ on NAA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer); it includes such "thanks, worked for me" as the very first example of when **to** flag as NAA.

- Have I misinterpreted the Answer?
- Does the FAQ guidance need to be updated?

Comment: Answers should answer the question, not merely restating what other answer already said. For that there's the upvote button!

Comment: I see what I think the problem is: I've expected too much of the NAA reviewers -- to look at the other answers for the context I meant with the flag: that it's a "me too" answer with the technical detail(s) copied in.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, that's exactly right. I agree it's confusing to users who hang out primarily on other SE sites, where the additional context of other answers, and the question, is taken into account when handling NAA flags. And lest you think SO mods are just being lazy ;) there's a good reason for doing it differently here. The scale of NAA answers is vastly different, and if they were handled like they are on other sites, that flag queue would get overrun, and it would become a substantially less efficient/useful flag.

Comment: I'm the mod who handled the NAA flags on that answer. I'm sorry my response was confusing. I should have spent more time composing, or used a response I've previously worked on, as my first pass usually needs dramatic cuts to fit in the permitted length, which is often confusing if not re-re-re?-edited. I chose to mark these NAA helpful, so didn't reach for those previously composed decline responses. The answers here covered the issue, so I'm upvoting those. To reiterate: if the answer text isn't *obviously Not An Answer*, then an NAA flag isn't appropriate. Use a custom flag and explain.

Comment: The scale of SO strikes again! I will continue to try and keep up with the norms. Thank you for the confirmation, @Makyen.

Comment: I flagged the same answer, and got the same response from @Makyen. I have to say that I didn't find it confusing and I completely understand what Makyen wanted to say and I agree. I am not new to flagging and my rationale behind this flag was the fact that at the time I flagged it, there were ***4*** comments under the answer indicating the fact that it's basically a thank-you answer (including a link to the "thanked" answer). I felt like this situation could easily be handled in the queue and didn't require "bothering" mods (even that the workforce is now bigger ;) )

Comment: Another possible course of action is to make a ["del-pls" request](https://socvr.org/faq#what-should-request-reasons-contain) in the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) indicating that the answer is a duplicate and of very low quality. In my experience, these requests are handled very quickly.

Comment: Fun twist -- I recently had a custom "NAA - this is a 'thank you' answer to (other answer)" flag declined with "declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags" so it seems there's mixed feelings on the moderation side.

Comment: i mean, what's confusing about that? NAA is for things that aren't answers. "thank you" isn't a answer, and as such is a great fit for NAA. No need for custom there.

Comment: @KevinB - I had been flagging NAA's (IMHO) as NAA's but then there's the case of non-obvious NAA's that we seem to want custom flags for, except ... when we don't. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JeffSchaller Could you share a link to that answer that got a declined flag?

Comment: Sure, @cigien, it's: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56412204/the-language-support-for-java-server-crashed-5-times-in-the-last-3-minutes-the/69754222#69754222.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Hmm, that's borderline. I would have flagged that as NAA myself, but it's tricky to explain why :( I don't think you were *wrong* to custom flag that, and I suspect some mods would have marked it helpful.

Comment: Humans (even moderators) are a messy bunch :) -- that's why I posted this Question: to help align my goals and to see what the goals of the community are.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This answer

> I have the same issue. Removing 'new' resolved my problem.

is absolutely an answer. The guidance in the FAQ you've linked to applies if the answer consisted solely of

> I have the same issue.

However, the second sentence

> Removing 'new' resolved my problem.

is definitely an answer. It's possibly a poor answer, it may not answer the question, it could certainly be improved with more explanation, etc. However, from the standpoint of a NAA flag, that's an answer.

The answer might actually just be referring to another answer that suggested the same thing, i.e. "to remove 'new'". However, that additional context requires a custom flag, since other answers are not something that is looked at necessarily, when handling NAA flags. For that matter, even the question, or comments on the answer are not guaranteed to be seen. If deciding whether an answer is NAA requires looking at *anything* other than just the text of the answer in isolation, avoid a NAA flag, and prefer a custom flag instead.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification -- I think your last paragraph nails it for me / this case.

Comment: Meh, it's a comment.

Comment: @RobertHarvey is it really a comment? Do we want comments saying "thanks, this fixed my problem"? I thought we'd stick with upvotes for that?

Comment: i mean, i'd rather it be a comment than an answer, at least comments can be quickly deleted.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I think what Robert is saying is that the answer reads like a comment, and so a NAA flag should have been accepted on that. I could be wrong about what Robert means, of course.

Comment: "I have the same issue" and "This solution worked for me" have always been comments and not answers, even if they are combined.  Not sure why we would ever think otherwise.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But the text didn't just say "this solution worked for me", it actually states the solution, namely "removing 'new'".

Comment: A distinction without a difference.  "This solution worked for me" also states the solution, or more accurately, restates it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I disagree completely. Actually stating a solution is categorically different from, well, not stating it.

Comment: Apparently we're talking past each other now.  I don't consider this issue controversial; phrases like "This solution worked for me" and "Using the new keyword worked for me" are part and parcel of pedestrian forums, the very reason for which comments were invented here, as a place to put things that clearly don't belong in answers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have to say, I find the phrasing of your comments a bit strange. You claim this issue is uncontroversial, and state it like it's a fact that this example is NAA, but surely you've seen the comment on the question *by a current mod who handles flags* stating otherwise? It's fine for you to say that you *want* things to be different, or that it *used* to be different, but to represent it as how it currently works is misleading. If you do feel strongly that it's uncontroversial, perhaps you could add an answer stating that, since I don't see another answer here taking that pov.

Comment: If you're taking issue with how it was flagged or how the flag was handled, I don't have an opinion about that; the NAA flag is widely misunderstood and overly legislated.  Nevertheless, my original observation is still valid; comments were invented specifically to have a place to put things that aren't really answers; "I had the same problem," and "This answer worked for me" and "The new keyword worked for me" all fall squarely into that camp.

Answer (score 20):

If you look at that answer *without any context*, it *looks like* an answer and it *might be* an answer (well, depending on the context). For example, if the question had no other answers, and the answerer said:

> I have the same issue. Removing 'new' resolved my problem.

That would be a poorly written equivalent of:

> You should not use 'new' for this. I've had this problem before and removing 'new' fixed it.

..which *is* a valid answer. But because the same thing has been said in other answers, the answerer here is essentially saying:

> I've used the solution suggested above and it worked for me.

Using NAA flags should be for answers that a moderator would easily see the reasoning without having to look for context. Otherwise, a custom flag with an explanation would be the best bet.

Comment: I'll echo my comment to cigien's answer: I think you've hit the nail on the head with the context mismatch. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I flagged it as NAA too.

NAA flag is not the best flag to be used in such situations. It might be obvious for the flaggers that this is just a "thanks" for the accepted answer, but for users handling the flags, this might look like a valid new answer. Mods see the flag in a very limited context. To be sure that the post gets deleted as it should, it's best to use a custom moderator flag and explain with a link which answer it is thanks for.

Comment: ["Do as I say, not as I do"](https://www.fowllanguagecomics.com/comic/do-as-i-say/)